# The app asks for update even after a successful update process(In-app-update)

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-update

Implemented in-app-update feature in my app.
The app asks for update when there is an update available.
When i hit the update button it goes to download screen and the app gets a restart after the download is complete with result code = Result_ok.
But it again pop up with update available.
What could be the reason behind this.

I have used the documentation for reference.
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates

Also it is immediate update.

I tried debugging for activity results and logged down result code = RESULT_OK.

Gradle files :-

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.0.0'
```

```
var appUpdateManager: AppUpdateManager? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard_navigation)

        sharedPreference = SharedPreference(this)

        appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this)

        checkUpdate()
}
```

```
private fun checkUpdate() {
    // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
    val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager?.appUpdateInfo
    // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
    Log.d(TAG, "Checking for updates")
    appUpdateInfoTask?.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
            && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
        ) {
            // Request the update.
            try {
                appUpdateManager!!.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    appUpdateInfo,
                    AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                    this,
                    MY_REQUEST_CODE
                )
                Toast.makeText(this, "Update Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.e(TAG, "Update available")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong.Contact Admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "No Update available")
        }
    }

    appUpdateInfoTask?.addOnFailureListener {
        Log.e(TAG, "checkUpdate: $it")
    }

}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        when (resultCode) {
            Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "" + "Result Ok")
                //  handle user's approval
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: update button clicked")
            }
            Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                {
                    //if you want to request the update again just call checkUpdate()
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "" + "Result Cancelled")
                //  handle user's rejection  }
            }
            ActivityResult.RESULT_IN_APP_UPDATE_FAILED -> {
                //if you want to request the update again just call checkUpdate()
                Log.d(TAG, "" + "Update Failure")
                //  handle update failure
                checkUpdate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```